# Filter Dataframe with Tidy Evaluation

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyeval

**I am handling a large dataset. First, for certain columns (X1, X2, ...), I am trying to identify a range of value (a, b) consists of repeated value (a > n, b > n). Next, I wish to filter row based on the condition which matches respective columns to result given in the previous step.**

Here is a reproducible example simulating the scenario I am facing,

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1122)

vecs <- lapply(X = 1:2, function(x) rep(c(1, 2, 3), times = 10) %>% sample() %>% head(10))
names(vecs) <- paste0("col_", 1:2)
dat <- vecs %>% as.data.frame()
dat

   col_1 col_2
1      3     2
2      1     1
3      1     1
4      1     2
5      1     2
6      3     3
7      3     3
8      2     1
9      1     3
10     2     2
```

I am able to identify the range by the following method,

```
# Which col has repeated value more than 3 appearances?
more_than_3 <- function(df, var){
    var <- rlang::sym(var)

    df %>% 
        group_by(!!var) %>% 
        summarise(n = n()) %>% 
        filter(n > 3) %>% 
        pull(!!var) %>% 
        range()
}
cols_name <- c("col_1", "col_2")
some_range <- purrr::map(cols_name, more_than_3, df = dat)
names(some_range) <- cols_name
some_range

$col_1
[1] 1 1

$col_2
[1] 2 2
```

However, to filter out values that fall outside the upper limit, this is what I do.

```
dat %>% 
    filter(col_1 <= some_range[["col_1"]][2], 
           col_2 <= some_range[["col_2"]][2])

  col_1 col_2
1     1     1
2     1     1
3     1     2
4     1     2
```

I believe there must be a more efficient and elegant way of filtering the result based on tidy evaluation. Can someone point me to the right direction?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you tell us what the expected output is for your test example?

Comment: Hi @Spacedman The filtering result shown above is my expected result. I wish to replace it with `tidy eval` principle.

Comment: I can't reproduce the results of your filtering above. (Also tidy evaluation is not meant to be efficient, it's meant to create a certain style of interfaces.)

Comment: Hi @lionel, I edited my code to make it reproducible. Also, thank you for your wonderful answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First let's try to create a small function that creates a single filter expression for one column. This function will take a symbol and then transform to string but it could be the other way around:

```
new_my_filter_call_upper <- function(sym, range) {
  col_name <- as.character(sym)

  col_range <- range[[col_name]]
  if (is.null(col_range)) {
    stop(sprintf("Can't find column `%s` to compute range", col_name), call. = FALSE)
  }

  expr(!!sym < !!col_range[[2]])
}
```

Let's try it:

```
new_my_filter_call_upper(quote(foobar), some_range)
#> Error: Can't find column `foobar` to compute range

# It works!
new_my_filter_call_upper(quote(col_1), some_range)
#> col_1 < 3
```

Now we're ready to create a pipeline verbs that will take a data frame and bare column names.

```
# Probably cleaner to pass range as argument. Prefix with dot to allow
# columns named `range`.
my_filter <- function(.data, ..., .range) {
  # ensyms() guarantees there won't be complex expressions
  syms <- rlang::ensyms(...)

  # Now let's map the function to create many calls:
  calls <- purrr::map(syms, new_my_filter_call_upper, range = .range)

  # And we're ready to filter with those expressions:
  dplyr::filter(.data, !!!calls)
}
```

Let's try it:

```
dat %>% my_filter(col_1, col_2, .range = some_range)
#>   col_1 col_2 NA.
#> 1     2     1   1
#> 2     2     2   1
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `map2`

```
library(purrr)
map2(dat, some_range,  ~ .x < .y[2]) %>%
      reduce(`&`) %>%
      dat[.,]
#     col_1 col_2
#1     2     2
#2     1     1
#3     1     2
#6     1     1
```

---

Or with `pmap`

```
pmap(list(dat, some_range %>% 
                     map(2)), `<`) %>% 
      reduce(`&`) %>%
      dat[.,]
```